# Validar dirección de domicilio utilizando expresiones regulares | Java

Tags: java, regex

Necesito validar un String que digite el usuario, el cual corresponde a su dirección de domicilio y debe tener el siguiente formato: **Calle 00 #00-00 Barrio** , la palabra **Calle** puede ser remplazada por **Carrera** o **Diagonal**. 
 Estoy definiendo el sgte patrón pero no me valida la expresión, aún no comprendo muy bien la utilización de los metacaracteres, cómo podría definir el patrón para validar correctamente la expresión? Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

```
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Calle|Carrera|Diagonal\\s\\d{2}\\s#\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s.");
                Matcher m;
                System.out.println("Digite direccion: ");
                direccion = sc.nextLine();
                m = p.matcher(direccion);
                if(m.matches()){
                    System.out.println("La dirrecion esta escrita correctamente");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("La direccion NO esta escrita correctamente");
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí te dejo la expresión regular corregida:

```
^(Calle|Carrera|Diagonal)\\s\\d{2}\\s#\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s[a-zA-Z\\s]+$
```

Te explico paso por paso lo que significa:

- **^**: indica el inicio de la cadena.
- **(Calle|Carrera|Diagonal)**: busca una de las tres palabras esperadas al inicio de la dirección.
- **\s**: busca un espacio en blanco.
- **\d{2}**: busca dos dígitos.
- **#**: busca el carácter "#" literal.
- **\d{2}-\d{2}**: busca dos dígitos, seguidos del carácter "-", seguidos
  de otros dos dígitos.
- **\s**: busca otro espacio en blanco.
- **[a-zA-Z\s]+**: busca una o más letras (mayúsculas o minúsculas) y/o
  espacios en blanco, que deben conformar el nombre del barrio.
- **$**: indica el fin de la cadena.

Ejemplo de tu código:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(Calle|Carrera|Diagonal)\\s\\d{2}\\s#\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s[a-zA-Z\\s]+$");
Matcher m;
System.out.println("Digite direccion: ");
direccion = sc.nextLine();
m = p.matcher(direccion);
if(m.matches()){
    System.out.println("La direccion esta escrita correctamente");
}else{
    System.out.println("La direccion NO esta escrita correctamente");
}
```